# cPanel - postwwwacct execution not happening through Blesta

Tags: cpanel

I have developed a script that installs wordpress after the creation of an account in cPanel using postwwwacct. The script works fine when I create an account from WHM. When I try to create an account from Blesta (an account billing software package) it does not.

The script is owned by root:root and has 755 permissions. Seems that any user should be able to execute it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to collect the verbose logs of the script including the error logs in your script itself and also check the cpanel whm logs file :

```
/usr/local/cpanel/logs/error_log
```

Normally it should be the issue as aby billing software already executes scripts as root and scripts under postwwwacct should be working.